# How to show that the following two problems are equivalent?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am doing exercise 5.40 of Convex Optimization book (By Boyd and Vandenberghe). In  the book it is mentioned that we can formulate the problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\lambda_{\max} \left( \sum_{i=1}^p x_i v_iv_i^T \right)^{-1}\\ \text{subject to} & 1^T x = 1\\ & x \succeq 0\end{array}$$

as the following problem $$\min. ~~~~ 1/t \\ s.t. ~~~~\sum _{i=1}^px_iv_iv_i^T \succeq tI \\ x \succeq 0\\ 1^Tx=1.$$ I tried to show that they are equivalent but in my attempt I get the following equivalent problem $$\max. ~~~~1/t\\ s.t. ~~~~\sum _{i=1}^px_iv_iv_i^T \succeq \frac{1}{t} I\\ x \succeq 0\\ 1^Tx=1.$$ In my attempt I assumed $G=(\sum_{i=1}^p x_i v_iv_i^T)^{-1}$ and then formulated the problem as $$\min. ~~~~ t \\ s.t.~~~~ \lambda_{max}(G)\leq t\\ G=(\sum_{i=1}^p x_i v_iv_i^T)^{-1}\\ x \succeq 0\\ 1^Tx=1.$$ Where am I wrong? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the objective function. Is that the maximum eigenvalue of an inverse matrix or the inverse of the maximum eigenvalue?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I really do not know. I wrote it as it is written in the book. And in my attempt I assumed that it is maximum eigenvalue of the the inverse matrix. But in the answer below supinf suggested it is actually the inverse of the maximum eigenvalue.

Comment: Are you sure the sign in the constraint of the second form isn't reversed? My feeling is that $\lambda_{\max}(A) = t \iff A \preceq t I$, and then the rest falls out.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H=\sum_{i=1}^p x_i v_iv_i^T$.

I think you understood the original problem to be

$$\min. ~~\lambda_{max} (H^{-1})\\ s.t.~~~~ 0\preceq x,~~~ 1^Tx=1,$$

whereas the original problem is actually meant to be

$$\min. ~~(\lambda_{max} (H))^{-1}\\ s.t.~~~~ 0\preceq x,~~~ 1^Tx=1.$$

This is not the same. I have not checked the of the work, but this mistake will lead to a wrong result.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong in the understanding of question statement. But I found if I replace $1/t$ by $g$ in the third problem of my post then I get the second problem of my post (Which BTW is the desired result.) But you are right perhaps I am wrong in understanding the question.